# What is most commonly used as a window manager for OpenGL nowadays?

Tags: opengl, sdl, glut

Glut seems rather old, and SDL also as if it's not the youngest anymore - what is being used as (cross-platform) window manager for OpenGL nowadays?

Answer (score 4):

Cross platform UI toolkit
1. wxwidgets
2. fltk
3. qt
4. glut(freeglut)
5. sdl

I have used glui. Sucks real bad(in terms of performance). There huge difference in performance penalty just by including glui(without actually using it) in your apps.

To be honest, i prefer platform specific UI toolkit. Faster. Reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you want to use it. Don't think there is a clear winner.

I like to use Qt because I'm familiar with it so it feels easy to me, and because I use it for other UI elements in my mostly windowed openGL apps.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it myself, yet, but want to in my next project. It seems to be very popular.
 [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) . It`s the "successor" to SDL written in C++

Answer (score 1):

I am using freeglut, but it is just a bit improved glut.

You can also use QT

Answer (score 1):

I think [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) is the best choice for small to medium applications/games. This type of libraries should be easy,small and fast with no extra services such as image helper functions and so on. GLFW is going to remove all helper functions to focus on the main goal.

QT is the best for graphics applications but not for games or small applications.